# Яндекс директ на динамических страницах | Ajax

Tags: javascript, яндекс-директ

Каким образом можно вывести объявления Яндекс директа на динамических страница? Сайт работает на ajax, и при прокрутке до конца страницы, подгружается новая статья, но при этом реклама уже не работает.

В документации яндекса и в поиске не нашел ответ.

Comment: Можно сделать отдельный ajax под метрику. Она будет инициализироваться как только прогрузится ajaxPage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в код вызова pageNumber и меняйте его в соответствии с загрузкой.
https://yandex.ru/support/partner2/web/products-rtb/partner-code.html#partner-code__neverending-scroll

Comment: Спасибо, только почему-то никакой реакции. Не в курсе, он может не сразу работает?

Comment: Он работает сразу. pageNumber должен быть разным при каждом вызове.
...            
Ya.Context.AdvManager.render({
                blockId: "R-A-12345-1",
                renderTo: "rtb-5-1",
                pageNumber: 1
   .....

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался)